# After calling the controller method error from template. Craft CMS 3

Tags: plugin-development

https://prnt.sc/qqs50o

I use the base plugin template from plugin factory.

Comment: Your error page says it is the route that is bad. Did you set a route for the controller?

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: Probably worth reading over the Craft and Yii routing docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html and https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing